# Flutter: Why i have shadow for ElevatedButton ( 0 elevation) while using .styleFrom() but havent with ButtonStyle()

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, elevation

[onPressed with .ButtonStyle()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ajl.png)

[onPressed with .styleFrom()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0Gl.png)

Hello guys, can you please explain me why i have shadow  for ElevatedButton ( 0 elevation) while using .styleFrom() but havent with ButtonStyle(). As i understand .styleFrom() function convert different parameters to MaterialStateProperty/ButtonStyleButton??? and then calls ButtonStyle() function by itself. So why if they are almost the same i have shadow in one case and not in the other? And how i can change this little shadow color? Or maybe there is another way to make zero elevation button with little shadow visible when pressed?

here is my code for both case:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
   style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(const Color.fromARGB(255, 215, 213, 245)),
      elevation:MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0),
      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(const EdgeInsets.all(0)),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))
      ),
   ),
   onPressed: () {},
   child: const Text('Starting stack: 5000',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black)),
)
```

and for .styleFrom()

```dart
...
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
   elevation:0,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
   ),
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
   onPrimary: Colors.white,
   primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 215, 213, 245),
   textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
),
...
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Already done

Comment: It would be better to include value instead of variable names while asking question, because those are unknown to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation about `styleFrom` from doc:

> The button's elevations are defined relative to the elevation parameter. The disabled elevation is the same as the parameter value, elevation + 2 is used when the button is hovered or focused, and elevation + 6 is used when the button is pressed.

[Flutter API docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/styleFrom.html)